# OpenGl Star drawing

Tags: delphi, opengl

I'm really new to OpenGL, which is a really bad thing to me :|
I need to draw a star(sort of) with openGl but I'm not really sure where I should start.

The results should be something like this:

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

the easiest way would be to draw a texture mapped quad with a "star" texture. You can read a  tutorial on texture mapping here: http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06

That tutorial teaches how to draw a cube using textures.
You just have to draw a single face, instead of all six.

The tutorial is written in C++, but near the end you can download the source of a Delphi version.

There are other effects you might want to add later, such as transparency. You can also read about that in the NeHe site. It has a lot of useful tutorials on OpenGL. It's a great place to learn OpenGL.

Comment: the problem is that I don't want to draw a texture mapped quad :|
All needs to be done with coding, no images needs to be used, I need this because I do need to change the light level.

Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Then you better get a different example. The image you show _looks_ like a textured quad, not like polygonal data. The texture itself could of course be generated from code, but that's completely unrelated to OpenGL. Can you perhaps provide us with a better example of what you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to OpenGL and if you're using Delphi, then most probably what you need is [GLScene](http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/HomePage). Mature, alive, very good quality of code and, of course, free.

Comment: I tried GLScene but I still cant find a way to avoid using mapped textures, I suppose this isnt so easy to do.

Comment: Ask them: 
news://forums.talkto.net/glscene.general
- or -
news://forums.talkto.net/glscene.support

At the time of writing are '59884 messages' in glscene.general. (I don't counted them, my Thunderbird says so :-))

HTH,

Answer (score 0):

Why not write an algorithm to generate a texture procedurally in code using a 2D GLuByte array as in the "checker.c" example in [Redbook](http://www.sgi.com/products/software/opengl/examples/redbook/)? Instead of following a perfect checkerboard pattern, figure out how to make a 2D texture of that star and map it into a quad using `glTexImage2D(...)`.